# Is it possible it see the progress of the Code Contracts static analyzer?

Tags: c#, .net, static-analysis, code-contracts

The static analyzer takes a long time to run. This is understandable, it is doing a lot of work. But while it runs in the background, it is difficult to tell what is going. Is the static analyzer running? Did it run into some problem the prevented it from completing? How close to completion is it?

Is there any way to see progress (or at the very least, a message that says "the static analyzer is currently running) for the static analyzer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want more output in the output window in Visual Studio.

Use `-show progress` in the Extra Static Checker Options under the Code Contracts Tab.

All available options: http://pastebin.com/pgV1gE2f

You can get this output with the option `/?`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the output window in Visual Studio.